# If `prefect` task failed, is it possible to re-run it with different `dask` parameters?

Tags: memory, dask, prefect

Consider a `prefect` task whose memory requirements are not known in advance. If the task fails because the worker does not have sufficient memory, is it possible to modify the `dask` worker parameters and re-run the task?

It would be great if there's a way to increase memory allocation per worker by some value after each failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give a general answer because it depends on your infrastructure.

1. For instance, if you want to provide custom keyword arguments to a Dask `cluster_class` ad-hoc per flow run, you could pass a dynamic function to a `DaskExecutor`'s `cluster_class`. This function could retrieve values such as `n_workers` from a  `Parameter` task, as follows:

```py
import prefect
from prefect import Flow, Parameter
from prefect.executors import DaskExecutor

def dynamic_executor():
    from distributed import LocalCluster

    # could be instead some other class e.g. from dask_cloudprovider.aws import FargateCluster
    return LocalCluster(n_workers=prefect.context.parameters["n_workers"])

with Flow(
    "dynamic_n_workers", executor=DaskExecutor(cluster_class=dynamic_executor)
) as flow:
    flow.add_task(Parameter("n_workers", default=5))
```

This means that you could start a new flow run with a different value of `n_workers` defined ad-hoc.

2. The second option would be to assign more memory in your run configuration on a per-flow-run basis - e.g. you could overwrite the `memory_request` set on a `KubernetesRun` from a UI:

```py
with Flow(
        FLOW_NAME,
        storage=STORAGE,
        run_config=KubernetesRun(
            labels=["k8s"],
            cpu_request=0.5,
            memory_request="2Gi",
        ),
) as flow:
```

The above code snippet defines 2 GB, but if you notice your flow run ended with an OOM error and you need more, you could trigger a new flow run from a UI with a higher memory request.

3. The last option would be to override the executor values directly in your flow definition:

```py
import coiled
from prefect.executors import DaskExecutor

flow.executor = DaskExecutor(
    cluster_class=coiled.Cluster,
    cluster_kwargs={
        "software": "user/software_env_name",
        "shutdown_on_close": True,
        "name": "prefect-cluster",
        "scheduler_memory": "4 GiB",
        "worker_memory": "8 GiB",
    },
)
```

As long as you use script storage (e.g. one of Git storage classes such as GitHub, Git, Gitlab, Bitbucket, etc) rather than pickle storage, and you commit your code with a modified value of `worker_memory`, this should be reflected in your new flow run because metadata about the executor is not stored on a backend - it's retrieved from your flow storage.